# Use SQL TimeDiff to populate PHP table data

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo, html-table

I have been searching Google for a good amount of time and I don't know if it is the way I am asking the question or what but I can not find anything even closely relevant to this. I have a PDO SQL statement :

```
 try 
    {
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, anum, first, last, signintime, counselorname, 
                        finishtime, TIMEDIFF(finishtime, signintime) AS Total_wait  FROM inoffice;");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchall();
    }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        die($e->getMessage());
        }
```

and then I have a table structured like so :

```
<table id='datatables' class='display'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>Session Id</th> 
                        <th>A Number</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Signin Time</th>
                        <th>Counselor Name</th>
                        <th>Finish Time</th>
                        <th>Total Wait Time</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                 <?php
                    foreach($result as $row) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?=$row['id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?=$row['anum'] ?></td>
                            <td><?=$row['first'] ?></td>
                            <td><?=$row['last'] ?></td>
                            <td><?=$row['signintime'] ?></td>
                            <td><?=$row['counselorname'] ?></td>
                            <td><?=$row['finishtime'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= ?></td>
                        </tr>
<?php
}
?>            

                    </tbody>
            </table>
```

My question is how on earth do I get the final part of my PDO select in that final td tag of my table? the part I am confused on is :

```
TIMEDIFF(finishtime, signintime) AS Total_wait
```

I want that to be able to be included in the last td of the table. Any help / trick / work around be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must treat `TIMEDIFF(finishtime, signintime) AS Total_wait`

as its own row from the database.

resulting in this :

```
 <td><?=$row['Total_wait'] ?></td>
```

now the table looks and works great :

[image]